# Update regex pattern to allow .xx instead of just 0.xx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression that I use to test against user input that expects currency. This statement allows an optional dollar sign, allows optional commas (as long as they are correctly placed), and allows a single decimal point as long as it's followed by at least another number.

```
^\$?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Examples like

- $12.12
- 0.34
- 12,000
- 12,000000

are all allowed by design. There is one however that doesn't match that I would like to. If a user wants to enter a number like .34 it must be proceeded by a zero. So 0.34 matches, but .34 doesn't.

Here's how I updated the statement to fix this.

```
^(\$?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*)?(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

I've made the entire statement before the decimal point a capturing group and made it optional. What I'm worried about now though, is that my entire regex statement enclosed by two capturing groups which are optional. I don't want a blank space to match this pattern and I think it will. Is there a better option for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Edit: My original statement doesn't match .12  The second updated statement does however, because the entire statement is wrapped in optional capturing groups, a blank space would match this pattern and that is not desired.

Comment: You should make a list of correct matches / correct no matches

Comment: Do you mean you do not want to match an empty string? Add `(?=.)` after `^`. Also, note that your regex does not match a *space*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, I think the OP wants to allow `.123`, i.e. a number with no leading non decimal number.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, `.123` is invalid according to the pattern.

Comment: Your regex [already appears to be working as you want](https://regex101.com/r/u6lr4t/1).  So then what is the actual problem?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. Currently .123 doesn't match. I would like it to match. I came up with a solution that DOES match .123 but I'm curious if there's a better solution then wrapping the entire statement in optional capturing groups. I don't want blank spaces to match.

Comment: @onTheInternet the `\.\d{1,2}` part of your pattern requires exactly one or two decimal digits to match - if you want to have it open ended, just use `\.\d+`. Concerning empty matches, see Wiktors comment, though the lookahead should be placed after `\$?`

Comment: @onTheInternet Your pattern is well written, `^(\$?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*)?(\.\d{1,2})?$` works as intended, and to prevent empty matches, you may add `(?=.)` or `(?!$)` after `^`: `^(?!$)(\$?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*)?(\.\d{1,2})?$`. Actually, there are other means to do it in JS, or any other languages.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually there is one issue with the pattern.  The thousands separator is optional, so `12345,678` would match.  Good enough for matching but maybe not for validation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in OPs samples there is `12,000000` so it seems not correctly/consistently applied thousand separators shouldn't force a failed match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're update to my pattern works flawlessly. Would you please put it in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, it is not actually what the question is about, but that is right for a general case. Can be re-written as `^(?!$)(\$?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*|\d+)?(\.\d{1,2})?$`. However, `12,000000` should also be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your optional group is the correct way to proceed. Note that non-capturing groups that are only used to group sequences of subpatterns are more efficient when you do not have to access the captured subvalues later.

The only thing you really miss is to avoid matching an empty string. You may achieve it using a positive lookahead `(?=.)` or `(?!$)` negative lookahead:

```
^(?!$)(?:\$?\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*)?(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4HO8hu/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!$)` - no end of string right after the start of string
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group

  - `\$?` - 1 or 0 `$` symbols
  - `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
  - `(?:`- start of a non-capturing group repeated 0+ sequences of

    - `,?` - 1 or 0 commas
    - `\d{3}` - 3 digits
  - `)*` - end of the non-capturing group
- `)?` - end of the optional non-capturing group
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 sequences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "or" syntax `|`

```
^\$?(\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*|0)(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

I would also suggest that you don't need to capture the inner groups of `(,\d{3})*`

```
^\$?(\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*|0)(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

`(\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*|0)` either an amount `\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*` or `0`